# event.keycode issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript code like below,

```
if (event.keycode != 37 && event.keycode != 39)
{
    var phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    if (phoneNumber.length < 1 && event.keyCode != 48)
        $('#phoneNumber').val(0)
    else if ((phoneNumber.length < 2 && event.keyCode == 48) )
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        $('#phoneNumber').val(phoneNumber)
}
```

keycode 37 = left arrow, keycode 39 = right arrow but when i pressed these keys on keyboard condition which is between if block being executed, i am using chrome browser, also i used the if statement below,

```
if (event.keycode != 37 || event.keycode != 39)
{
    var phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    if (phoneNumber.length < 1 && event.keyCode != 48)
        $('#phoneNumber').val(0)
    else if ((phoneNumber.length < 2 && event.keyCode == 48) )
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        $('#phoneNumber').val(phoneNumber)
}
```

urgent helps greatly appreciated,

Thanks everybody.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: is it in a function? from where u getting the event object?

Comment: **if (event.keycode != 37 || event.keycode != 39)** are you sure this is a correct condition? it means any keycode will pass the condition.And also what is your question?

Comment: Anyone see the difference between the block codes? You also missing some ending `;`

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes i see my question has inconsistency and does not have capability of being a question, but Tim has been answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is capitalization: it's `keyCode`, not `keycode`. Your code is using them inconsistently.

Comment: Thanks Tim you helped very much!